# Permissions error in C# application, System.Net.NetworkInformation?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq, permissions

In folder AppCode `MyUrl.class`

C#

```
MyUri a = new MyUri();
private Fun1()
{
    a.SelectFromDB();    // This function errors out. (see below)
}

 DataClassesDataContext dc = new DataClassesDataContext();
 private fun2()
 {
     // This code works fine.
     var a = from v in dc.DB 
     select v;
 }
```

What does the following error mean?

> request for the permission of type system.net.networkinformation
>   permission system version=2.0.0.0 culture=neutral,publickkey
>   Token=b77a5c561934e089

Comment: What does the SelectFromDB method of MyUri DO?  That code appears critical to answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

You have two different functions

```
   MyUri a = new MyUri();   
private Fun1()   
{      
 a.SelectFromDB();    
// This function errors out. (see below)   
}   




  DataClassesDataContext dc = new DataClassesDataContext();  
         private fun2()  
         {      
              // This code works fine.      
              var a = from v in dc.DB       
              select v;  
         }
```

Seems both doesnt hv any relationship. Also SelectFromDB method is doing what. What type of class is MyUri. Paste some code of MyUri.

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering if you are not running into an issue with your LINQ query.

See the following MS thread for some strange LINQ behavior:

[how to make a query in linq to data services](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataservices/thread/856a074c-70ab-4f45-9f2e-ab4954a138fd)